# Using/looping response from Ajax call from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling an `Ajax` function from another function and want to get the response and then parse the `Json` in order to assign it to new `div`s.

The call is made like this:  `thedata = GetChequesByBatchID(batchId);` and this is the response:

[image]

Then, I am trying to loop through the response, but this is where the problem is. I am not sure how to get the response and loop through the `thedata`. This data should be assigned to the `htmlFromJson` so it will be inserted as group of `divs` in the `TR`. Any ideas?

My function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (params) {
        var batchId;
        var thedata;
        var htmlFromJson = "";
        $('.showDetails').click(function () {
            // Show Details DIV
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.details').toggle('fast');
             batchId = $(this).data('batchid');
             thedata = GetChequesByBatchID(batchId);

             var json = jQuery.parseJSON(thedata);

             $.each(json, function () {

                     htmlFromJson = htmlFromJson + ('<div class="ListTaskName">' + this.ChequeID + '</div>' +
                         '<div class="ListTaskDescription">' + this.ChequeNumber + '</div>' +
                     '<div class="ListTaskDescription">' + this.ChequeAccountNumber + '</div>' +
                     '<div class="ListTaskDescription">' + this.ChequeAmount + '</div>');

            });
        }).toggle(
            function () {
                // Trigger text/html to toggle to when hiding.
                $(this).html('Hide Details').stop();
                $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr class='456456'><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + '<div class="zzss">' + htmlFromJson + '</div></td></tr>');              
            },
            function () {
                // Trigger text/html to toggle to when showing.
                $(this).html('Show Details').stop();
                //$(this).find('.zoom').remove();
                $('tr.456456').remove();
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

My Ajax function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetChequesByBatchID(BatchID) {
        var xss;
        var qstring = '?' + jQuery.param({ 'BatchID': BatchID });
      return $.ajax({
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/DesktopModules/PsaMain/API/ModuleTask/GetChequesByBatchID")%>' + qstring,
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                jQuery.parseJSON(result); //the response
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("1 " + response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("2 " + response.responseText);
            }
        });
        return xss;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` is async operation (if you don't include `async:false` option which is not recommended) so your `GetChequesByBatchID` function immediately returns either `$.ajax` object or `undefined`. Correct usage of `$.ajax` is to call DOM changing methods from `success` or `error` parts of `$.ajax`.